# I can fetch one word, but not the other one, how can this be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making a CMS with an edit button. When you click the edit button it should everything from the JSON file back to the CMS side so you can actually edit.
However when I try to fetch my `word` I can only fetch one while I have 2 `word` in my JSON.

This is how my JSON looks like:

```js
{
  "main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "getExerciseTitle": "TestToConfirm",
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "application": "lettergrepen",
    "main_object": {
      "title": "TestToConfirm",
      "language": "nl_NL",
      "exercises": [{
          "word": "huishoudelijk",
          "syllables": [
            "huis",
            "houdelijk",
            "",
            ""
          ]
        },
        {
          "word": "Kleedt u zich maar uit.",
          "syllables": [
            "Kleed",
            "u",
            "zich",
            "uit"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "dataType": "json"
  }
}
```

This is how I am trying to loop through my `word` so I can fetch it all. I do have to note that I am going to fetch the `syllables` aswell and i'm not entirely sure if it's bad to create 2 different loops to fetch the data. Or is it recommended to do it both in 1 loop?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
    // console.log(json);


    var exercisetitle = json.main_object.getExerciseTitle;
    // console.log(exercisetitle);
    $("#getExerciseTitle").val(exercisetitle);

    var exercise = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;


    $.map(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
      var myindex = 1;
      $("#addOpdracht").click();
      $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + myindex).val(exercise.word)
      myindex++;
    });

  });

});
```

The code of `exerciseGetWordInput_`:
The #addOpdracht is just a button that creates new exercise blocks. I don't think that has much to do with how to loop or the possible cause of my app failing.

```
function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput_' + id + ' form-group form-control ExerciseGetWordInput',
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[' + exerciseAudioInput + ']',
    'placeholder': 'Exercise',
    'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput',
    'required': true
  });
  return wInput;
}
```

Comment: @Nikhil Aggarwal if you read this, your code was correct. It was a mistake from my side. I had the counter on 1  instead of 0. So thank you.

Comment: Why would you click  $("#addOpdracht") again and again? Or do you only have ONE exercise?

Comment: I have more exercises. However I do so to create the exercise blocks so it can append the words inside the input fields

Comment: If the fetching of the JSON works, then REMOVE the fetch and please create a [mcve] using an example with at least two exercises and the relevant HTML to insert. Click the `<>` button and create a snippet

Comment: Or is the issue solved by moving the  var myindex = 1; outside the map? And why use map instead of a normal loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `var myindex = 1` outside the loop

```
var myindex = 1;
$.map(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
  $("#addOpdracht").click();
  $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + myindex).val(exercise.word)
  myindex++;
});
```

OR you can also avoid use of extra variable like following and use `each` instead

```
$.each(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
  $("#addOpdracht").click();
  $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + i).val(exercise.word) // starts with 0
});
```

Comment: I can accept your answer in 7 minutes. your code was correct. It was my wrongdoing to start the counter at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @D.Sof - Glad to help you :)

Comment: Why use map at all? `$.each(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
  $("#addOpdracht").click();
  $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + i).val(exercise.word) // starts with 0
});` makes more sense - and the click is horrible, Instead call the code in the handler that the click is using

Comment: I would use ID instead of class when you are creating unique exercises anyway

Answer (score 0):

1. Use each
2. use IDs
3. execute the function you would normally execute on click.

```js
var data = {
  "main_object": {
    "id": "new",
    "getExerciseTitle": "TestToConfirm",
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "application": "lettergrepen",
    "main_object": {
      "title": "TestToConfirm",
      "language": "nl_NL",
      "exercises": [{
          "word": "huishoudelijk",
          "syllables": [
            "huis",
            "houdelijk",
            "",
            ""
          ]
        },
        {
          "word": "Kleedt u zich maar uit.",
          "syllables": [
            "Kleed",
            "u",
            "zich",
            "uit"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

$.each(data.main_object.main_object.exercises, function(_,exercise) {
  addOpdracht(exercise)
});

function addOpdracht(exercise) {
  var $container = $("#exerciseContainer"),
    count = $container.length,
    $div = $("<div/>").addClass("exerciseDiv"),
    $input = $("<input/>", {
      type: "text",
      id: "exerciseGetWordInput_" + count,
      value: exercise.word
    })   
  $div.append($input);
  $container.append($div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exerciseContainer"></div>
```